# ¿Como puedo convertir una variable de entrada tipo varchar "1,2,3" a un 1,2,3 en Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

les comento que creé este procedimiento almacenado para generar el pivote de una tabla en Mysql.

Funciona bien, solo que la variable de entrada `_cmp_id` la paso como varchar '1,2,3', cuando realizo la comparación en and `ccc.cmp_id in (_cmp_id)` pasa como `ccc.cmp_id in ('1,2,3')` (solo me hace la busqueda por el primer elemento, el resto lo ignora). No he encontrado de que pase como `ccc.cmp_id in (1,2,3)`.

Aquí les dejo el procedimiento almacenado, que me retorna un varchar con las condiciones para realizar el pivote.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PIVOTE;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE PIVOTE
(
    IN _cmp_status varchar(30),
    IN _cmp_id varchar (30),
    IN _adm varchar(30),
    IN _d_start varchar(30),
    IN _d_end varchar(30),
    OUT _var_out varchar(20000)
)

BEGIN
    
    SET @sql= '';
    
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'MAX(CASE WHEN ct_agents_answers_form.questions_id = ',
              ct_questions.question_id,
              ' THEN IFNULL(answer_text,answer_text) ELSE NULL END) AS pregunta'
        )
      SEPARATOR ', ') INTO @sql
    FROM camp_cdr
    left join ct_call_campaign ccc ON ccc.cmp_id = camp_cdr.camp_name
    left join admin_master am ON am.adm_id = camp_cdr.agent_id
    inner join ct_form f ON f.form_id = (SELECT form_id FROM ct_agents_answers_form where call_id = camp_cdr.call_id limit 1)
    inner join ct_agents_answers_form ON ct_agents_answers_form.call_id = camp_cdr.call_id
    inner join ct_questions ON ct_questions.question_id = ct_agents_answers_form.questions_id
    left join ct_answers ON ct_answers.answer_id = ct_agents_answers_form.answer_id
    where ccc.cmp_status = _cmp_status
    and ccc.cmp_id in (_cmp_id)
    and am.adm_is_admin = _adm
    and start_time between _d_start and _d_end;

    SET _var_out = @sql;
    
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

El llamado del procedimiento es así:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SET @sql='';
SET @date_start = '2022-02-13';
SET @date_end = '2022-02-14';
SET @cmp_id = '1'; -- Con '1' me trae el resultado esperado con '1,2' solo me trae el resultado como si le pasara '1'
SET @adm = 'agent';
SET @cmp_status = 'Active';

CALL PIVOTE(@date_start,@date_end,@cmp_id,@adm,@cmp_status,@sql);

SELECT @sql;
```

Si existe una manera de hacer esto agradecería que lo comentaran

Comment: Una opción es usar la función [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Ejemplo: `... and FIND_IN_SET(ccc.cmp_id, _cmp_id) ...`.